# Where to mount a headlight if the handlebar is obscured by a basket

Tags: headlights, visibility

I have a permanently mounted basket in front of the handlebars (because I have a child seat on the rack in the back). I also have a headlight on the handlebars ([this one](http://www.cateye.com/en/products/detail/HL-EL135/), if anyone cares). If the basket is empty, it is somewhat visible, through the mesh that basket is made of. However, if I put anything in the basket, the headlight is useless.

I should mention that I also have a dynamo powered headlight below the basket, but I turn it on only when it's really dark, as the bottle dynamo noticeably slows down the bike.

Any ideas where to move the headlight from the handlebars? To the fork perhaps? That can be a problem as it would point a bit upwards then, and also would be partially obscured by the wheel itself.

Comment: mount it to the basket seems obvious

Comment: "[my headlight] is somewhat visible, through the mesh that basket is made of." No, it's practically invisible because it's much dimmer than any other light on the road.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a rather quick solution and possible permanent fix if the look suits you, you could get a piece of plastic PVC pipe just long enough and the approximate diameter of your handlebars, and just affix the plastic PVC pipe to the front of the basket, and mount the light on the PVC tube. If the basket is the wire type, you could slot the bottom of the pipe an it would slip right over the top of the basket and then the clamp for the light could run through the wire and around the light to secure it. This same thing could likely be accomplished with other types of baskets as long as there was a good support at the top of the basket. Just a thought for a quick and cheap possibility using the same light.

Comment: That's probably what I'm going to do. The basket is not  of wire, but of mesh (this one to be exact: http://parts.capriolo.com/proizvodi/korpe/korpe-koja-se-montira-na-korman-za-mtb), the only problem I see is fixing in such way that it stands still and doesn't rattle. There's also a minor aesthetic problem, as the most PVC pipes over here are white or green, and my bike being red/black. :)

Comment: If you do deide on the PVC route, it could be made ready for paint and be painted any color you desire.

Answer (score 11):

Something like this accessory is what you need:

[image: Rixen & Kaul Light-Clip. For Front Basket]

[image: Rixen & Kaul Light-Clip. For Front Basket]

Can be fitted onto wired or meshed bicycle baskets.
This specific model is made by the "Rixen & Kaul" and can be found in many online shops. E.g. [Amazon - Rixen & Kaul Light-Clip Basket Fitting - Black](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B004JHWW4C).

Answer (score 10):

Helmet lights are good.  Usually in addition to one on the handlebars.

**The pro** of the helmet light is that you can light up things that are not directly infront of you.  The pro of having an additional light is that it increases the chance of being seen and adds extra illumination for you.

**The con** is that if you are looking to the side and a car is coming from the front they will not see the light shining at them, so you should not have a helmet light as your only light.

Comment: While this sidesteps the question, helmet lights really are awesome to have.  When you point it right at a driver, they are sure to see you.

Comment: When I'm driving, I find helmet lights really confusing. A friend of mine had a red one on his helmet, I could never tell what direction he was going.

Comment: I personally find helmet lights to be somewhat rude in a dense city. Seems that at least a few fellow commuters shine theirs in my eyes each evening during my ride home from the office. Helmet lights for the trail or rural road, bar/frame/fork lights for the city

Comment: @alex This may be an advantage.  If people see you but are noticeably confused this may increase their caution.

Comment: Another con is the weight.

Comment: @ Paul H, IMHO quite the contrary. With helmet light one can look slightly away from fellow cyclists.

Comment: I am curious as to how you could have your head turned to the side *for so long while riding that a car would miss seeing you*, without having other problems.

Comment: I didnt say they would miss seeing you, just that if the light is not shining straight at them they may not realize that you are driving in their direction.

Comment: @sixtyfootersdude No. A confused road user is a dangerous road user. We need to _decrease_ the cognitive load, not increase it.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - There have been numerous studies that have indicated confused motorists are more cautious.  Bikes that are swerving side to side get noticeably larger passing distances.  Women get larger passing distances then men.  I agree that in general you want to be have in a predictable way but projecting a level of unpredictability will give you more space on the road.

Comment: @sixtyfootersdude Your examples have nothing to do with confusion. Also, as I recall, the statistics used to claim that women are given a wider berth than men were dubious. (I don't remember the details but it was something like the average passing distance of women being higher only because drivers who gave adequate room were likely to give a bit more for women. So men and women are equally likely to be passed too close and the only difference was that there were more drivers passing women at very large distances than men. But, once the car is more than, eg, 2m away, it doesn't really matter)

Comment: Minor downside - in some locations head-mounted lights are not legal.  Best to check first.

Answer (score 7):

There are various extension mounts you can buy or build to reposition lights and other handlebar-mount items.  I have a purchased unit that can be adjusted maybe 2" higher than the bar, and which can mount on either the bar or the stem.  You can also craft something with a short piece of plastic pipe, a few screws and brackets, and some cleverness.

Answer (score 6):

The obvious places are on the basket, on the fork crown, or on the fork itself, although they may require mounting hardware or a different light altogether. Reading [this](http://www.peterwhitecycles.com/light-mounts.asp) may get you some ideas. Looking at the [Reelight](http://www.reelight.com/) line-up may also spark your imagination.

Or you could also go with unconventional solutions like [Revolights](http://revolights.com/).

Answer (score 5):

Attach a pipe or pole to the basket and hey presto! Another "handlebar"!

Photos from [Bike Hacks](http://www.bikehacks.com/bikehacks/2015/08/pvc-basket-mount.html) contributors:

[image: PVC pipe]

[image: wooden dowel]

[image: metal pipe]

Comment: With those apehangers you could fit the lights up near the top curve and they would shine over most loads.  Nice work.

Answer (score 2):

Lucky's solution can be done with any sort of short, black tubular thing.  E.g. an old film canister, or a stub of wood or dowel.  Use some cheap wire snips to open up the mesh to accommodate the light-mount's adjustable strap about 1/2 inch below the top-front edge, and wrap the strap around the black object and the basket (through hole and over the edge).  Cinch it tight and you'd have as much rattling as you would have from attaching to the handlebars in the first place.  You could even use some rubber from a used tube or other bike-reflector/light clamps and put it between the block and the basket.

```
               [Basket below]

                       =====<    [light, on "O" tube]
                      /--\
                |     ||O|
[Bike here,     |     \--/
 forward        |      |
 is to the      |      |
 right]         |      |
                --------
```

Another idea is to get a small (3-4 inch) piece of flat metal bar, e.g. a [metal bracket with holes](http://boying.b2bage.com/product-brackets/251198/metal-bracket.html) (pref. aluminum, plastic).  At the bottom of your basket, either on side near front or even straight forward, use wire snips to make a little horizontal slit for the bar to go through, but so it can stay flat with the bottom of the basket.  Now you lay the bar there with half in, half out, tied to the bottom with black zip ties or a nut and bolt.  You could zip tie the light to the bar itself or maybe screw a piece of wood dowel or pipe to the end and attach the light to that.

```
               [Basket below]

                |      |
[Bike here,     |      |
 forward        |      |           [light, at end of bar, maybe with a tube.]
 is to the      |      |  =====<
 right]         |    ______O
                --------
```

Depending on how you can recharge the light, and on whether you mind reaching in to press the power button, you could even snip a big enough hole in the front of the basket so the light would simply lie flat (adjusted for angle) on the bottom of the basket, inside, with only the lens up against the outside.  This could use black zip ties and be very discrete.

```
               [Basket below]

                |      |
[Bike here,     |      |
 forward        |      |
 is to the      |      |           [light, strapped inside]
 right]         | =====<
                --------
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer and for the ASCII effort! I like the third suggestion, the basket is even slightly slanted forward, so no need for angle adjustment. The only problem would be removing and putting back the light (when leaving the bicycle somewhere). Perhaps I should buy the cheapest and just forget about it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Zip tie the light to the side of your basket.  May take several tries to get the angle right and will not work on all baskets.  This has allowed me to still be able to reach the light while riding.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

ELECTRA LED BASKET FRONT LIGHT

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles! Welcome to Bicycles SE. We're looking for answers with [more detail](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please consider expanding your answer to further elaborate on the benefits and drawbacks of this light, or. particularly since this is an old question, why your suggestion is better than the previous answers. A short answer like this is likely to get downvoted, flagged for moderator intervention, and possibly deleted.

Comment: If you go with something like this - a backing / load spreader plate behind the light might be a good idea.  Doesn't have to be thick, even a chunk of plastic hacked from an icecream bucket would be better than nothing.  Use largish washers too.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the legal requirements are for a light for you, but if its a be-seen light (as opposed to a see-the-road light)  then Electroluminescent wire is great at showing where you are.  Also known as "EL Wire" this stuff is like a light plastic rope, that can be woven or flexed.

Connect it to a suitable power source, and it will glow in whatever colour you chose.  Some are 3V, some USB/5V, and some are 12V.    I've run a 12V one on 18V and it worked fine, but no idea how that would impact longevity.

[image: From https://biketoeverything.com/2019/07/25/6-tips-burning-man-bike/]

Not the best photo, but you can see the blue line around the front of the basket.  EL wire can be held on the outside with a series of white cableties / slip ties which won't block the light.  And the battery can be put inside the basket.  Additionally, little of the light will be visible to the rider and so won't reduce night-vision.

Downsides

- This does not illuminate your surroundings more than perhaps half a metre, and only in a general way.  There is minimal "throw" so if you want to light up the road, you're back to square one
- Some people can hear these things - they use a high frequency AC waveform to excite the wire, and it sounds like a mosquito repellent.  Which might also be an advantage.

You can get many different colours, and they're generally waterproof enough.  The power connector would be the weakest point, into a USB battery bank/power bank.

Answer (score -3):

There is still no solution.

[1] The KLICKfix accessories do not work.  They look good, but the lamp vibrates as you ride, causing stress where the KLICKfix meets the basket and eventually the vibration causes it to cut through your wire basket.  I've had two wire baskets damaged like this.

[2] The Electra LED lights are too feeble.

[3] Attaching a pipe with PVC is a pretty clunky solution.

What's needed is a mount which could attach to the bottom of the basket, either above the bottom, or under it. The problem is that each lamp manufacturer's mount is different, so if Smart (e.g.) designed a mount to attach to the base of wire baskets, it would only fit Smart lights. So it would be uneconomic to manufacture.

I don't know what the answer is.

Comment: Welcome to SE - thank you for contributing.  Rather than posting a "I don't know the answer" try posting what would/might fix these failings, and/or post something that does answer OP's needs.

Comment: If that is meant to correct me, I think it is misguided. I was trying to warn people that some suggested answers, like KLICKfix, do not work (in that case marketing a pricey product which damages one's basket). Is that not a fact which is worth adding to the discussion? I was also trying to indicate that the search for a solution remains open - which hopefully will inspire others to suggest new solutions. Is that not worth doing?